# Invariant k-form and inner derivation: relation used in symplectic geometry.

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I am reading *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*, by McDuff et al.

At the end of page 97, it seems to suggest that if $\omega$ is a $k$-form over $M$ and $\psi: M \rightarrow M$ is an $\omega$ invariant diffeomorphism. That is, $\psi^* \omega = \omega$, then,
$$\iota(\psi^* X) \omega = \psi^*(\iota(X) \omega).$$

Here, $\iota$ represents the [inner derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product).

How can I show this?

---

PS: Actually, in the book, $\psi_t: M \rightarrow M$ is a smooth family of $\omega$ invariant diffeomorphisms. But I guess it is not important for this post.

Comment: Hint:  insert dummy arguments on both sides and apply the definitions:$$\psi^*\omega(X_1,\cdots,X_k):=\omega(\psi_*X_1,\cdots,\psi_*X_k)$$ $$\iota_X\omega(Y_1,\cdots,Y_{k-1}):=\omega(X,Y_1,\cdots,Y_{k-1})$$

Comment: @Kajelad: I guess I didn't attempt for the "upper/lower" *. Is it true that $\psi^*X = \psi_*^{-1}X$?

Comment: Yes.  ($\psi_*$ and $\psi^*$ are respectively called the pushforward and pullback of $\psi$, by the way.)